# Hide /public in URL, Symfony in subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

So I have this structure:

```
root
 - webapp
 - wordpress
 - some_php_files
```

I'm trying to redirect only the files in `/webapp` and not the rest in root. Remove `public` if `webapp` before.

```
show in url  | instead  of

domain.com/webapp | domain.com/webapp/public

domain.com/webapp/page | domain.com/webapp/public/page
```

I manage to redirect everything or nothing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /webapp/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect the "instead" urls to the "show" urls? Or do you want to internally rewrite the "show" urls" to the "instead" urls? Or both?

Comment: Forget it, it doesn't matter. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @dario did you solve the issue? I'm too stuck in this problem.